# Tweepy Block user with specific words in their bio

Tags: python, tweepy

I just started to use tweepy for fun things (create bot etc) and I was thinking about a thing can we block people with specific word in their bio? Like racist words or hateful words? With the method user.description unfortunately I see this only for a specific ID.

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user bio with

```
user = API.get_user(id/user_id/screen_name)
print(user.description)
```

You can block users with

```
API.create_block(id/screen_name/user_id)
```

There are also methods to list the blocked users, unblock, etc.. see [Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html)

The processing of the bio content is not provided by Tweepy, this is more related to the text and sentiment analysis. You can google and find lots of resources and some free Dataset (if you just want to do a lookup for example).

Comment: yes but it's only for one person you should change the ID everytime you want to block someone right ? can't we block for example 250 accounts at the same time because of their bio ?

Comment: You can fetch followers (API.followers()) or search for users (API.search_users((), then process the lists you fetch

Comment: ok thanks and in API.followers I set  in () the user right ? For example API.followers(BillGates) and I get an array of every followers of bill gate ?

Comment: If no user is specified, it finds the followers of the authenticated user, otherwise you can pass the user id or user screen name